# How to change end point url in ibm watson with facebook chat bot

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, facebook-chatbot

`The watsonplatform.net endpoint URL is retired. Update your code to use the specific watson.cloud.ibm.com URL for your service.`

I am getting the above error in my facebook chat bot.
I have created new API service credentials as per this link
 `https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-endpoint-change`

and added it to ibm cloud.

`https://website.region.mybluemix.net/`
getting 404 for this.

Where should the newly created api endpoint be updated for facebook chat bot to work ?

Comment: Have you revisited the Facebook integration in Watson Assistant? You probably need another webhook URL.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the Watson Assistant integrations topic that is linked to from [the end](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-endpoint-change#endpoint-links) of that endpoint change topic?

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-release-notes#6April2021

There is some information about facebook,

> For a Facebook Messenger integration that is over 7 months old, make sure the Callback URL is using the proper endpoint.

with more details.